# maven, deploy a desktop application

Tags: java, maven

I am switching from ant to maven.

To keep things simple, my application is a swing application that connects to a database.
I want it to be packaged in a jar file.
The application requires an external library, that is Microsoft sql server library, contained in a jar file: sqljdbc4-3.0.jar.

So i tryed to include this library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

but when launching the jar, i get the exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

This problem is already documented in other stackoverflow questions; i'm talking of this just to get to the point.
My idea (maybe naive) is the following, i would like to

- create a jar with only my code.
- create a distribution that contains in a directory (lib) all my libraries.
- the manifest file to correctly reference all the libraries.

Searching around, i've found that each one of this issues is performed by a different maven plugin: jar plugin, dependency plugin and assembly plugin. 
Is this the way to go? 
I don't feel it right because i've undesrtood that maven would handle easily "regular" configurations and this solutions of the three plugins seems a bit over-complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add these plugins to pom

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

src/main/assembly/assembly.xml

```
<assembly>
    <id>assembly</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

run assembly

```
mvn clean package assembly:single
```

Comment: Maven really only makes things "easier" if you understand what it's doing for you.  Most of the time it is just frustrating to get it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is the maven way. By the way: the jar plugin and the dependency plugin are included always in a maven build and there should be no need to configure them.

Additionally a good help could be the [appassembler](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) that creates a distributable including all jar files needed.

Comment: Just a note: for strictly creating "superjars", you only need the assembly plugin.

Comment: But the idea of the OP tells us that he wants a jar with his own code and a lib directory with the other jars. This is no Uberjar but better to be achieved with appassembler.

Comment: actually, i'm struggling with the libraries not being added to the classpath... i think the problem is too many plugins, so i don't think the solution is adding one more plugin. by the way: <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <archive>
             <manifest>
               <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
               <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
             </manifest>
           </archive>
         </configuration>

Comment: Please look at the appassembler plugin and try it. I have a project with (at least) 100 jar files to include and it works flawless without having to modify any file.